# How to develop an iPad web app to cope with wifi outages

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, wifi

I'm looking at developing a web app that is primarily aimed at iPads.  It will be a fairly standard html+jQuery client, but I was pondering making it resilient to wifi outages as it will be used a lot at conferences where wifi may be patchy.  I was thinking of using json-formatted objects stored in lots of cookies, with captured data also being stored in 'json cookies', with a task running that will poll for a server connection and upload my json cookies when it can.

Does this overall architecture sound workable, and can anyone suggest a better way to manage client-side cacheing of objects and data?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [offline web capabilities of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/), together with [HTML5 client-side storage](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/) of the browser instead of cookies. This is the way to go nowadays, especially with the full support of this by the browser on the iPad.